# Hard drive fan spinning at over 6100rpm?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I have a late 2009 iMac with the following hard drive:
Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,107,862,016 bytes)
Model: Hitachi HDT721050SLA360 
Revision: ST0KA36E

This is happening nearly everyweek, usually overnight when there is nothing happening on it. When i come back in the morning the fan is spinning at over 6100 rpm. Normally it spins at around 1100 rpm.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you monitored the hard drive temperatures being reported?  If so, what have they been?

Comment: Yes, they are currently at 122(F) with the fan operating at normal speed of 1100 rpm.  

When it was spinning fast, it was down to around 110(F).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the system is doing some indexing / updating itself overnight and doing a lot of hard drive activity in the process.

Does the fan speed correct itself?

Comment: No it does not correct it self, and there is minimal activity whenever it happens. There are no programs running when it happens.

Comment: How does the problem get corrected then? On reboot? Something you do in software?